# Drilling holes in concrete 1/2" inch apart

Tags: concrete, generator, pad

Went through Costco to get a generator installed. Generac 25kW. That was a mistake. The contractor they use has been nothing but problems.

I got a pad poured to exact dimensions but yet these guys managed to mess up the placement of the generator. It is off center, 1.5" on one side and 2.5" on the other. Also, it is out of code. It should be 36" from the fence on the left side, it is 35.5". It should be >=18" on the right, is 19" which is ok on that side.

Problem is that it is anchored in with two lag bolts on the left side of the generator. Would it be a problem drilling two new holes .5" from the old holes? My concern is the concrete cracking due to the spacing. Also, water getting in the old holes and expanding during freezing winter.

Right now it is the contractor's problem and needs to be fixed. If I don't address this now and wait until I sell the house, it will be my problem.

How would you CORRECTLY fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would ask Costco how they were going to fix it.

Comment: Talk to Costco about botched installation.

Comment: centering doesn't matter.  If the inspector goes cites you for 1/2" hit that skirt with a sledgehammer a few times.

Comment: I'd be worried about the neighbors looking for any excuse whatsoever to have it moved elsewhere. Ain't nobody checking that 1/2" with a tape unless they're looking for arbitrary reasons to screw you, and that tells you right away that you're not going to sell to that guy anyway w/o taking hits all over the place.

Comment: How about filling the old holes with chemical anchor and after it cures completely, drill close to them, reducing the risk of breaking out into the old ones (now filled completely)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would leave it as is unless the inspector requires that it be moved 1/2 inch. You can try drilling new holes but that close to the old ones I would not expect it to be successful. If it's not successful you can drill a bigger hole and set a stud with epoxy. You could also mount the generator to pressure treated wood and then fasten the wood to the concrete.

Does it need to be 36" from the fence or from the property line? Usually setbacks are calculated from the property line.

Comment: I would leave it too.   And consider moving the whole pad if you have to (and you can get leverage to move it).

Comment: To elaborate:  Get pressure treated wood.  Make holes for the existing lag bolts, then put new holes 1/2" away.  Put the treated wood on the existing lag bolts, and bolt the wood in the new holes to the generator.  You will need a drill press.

Comment: _If_ the inspector demands this to be fixed, before starting this process, contact Costco to have _them_ do it.

Comment: I don't have an inspector looking at this right now. My concern is when I sell the house, it becomes my problem. Right now it is the contractor's problem. Anyone familiar with Costco's process and how to address this with them?

Comment: so drilling holes 1/2" from the previous holes will cause the pad to crack?

Comment: It won't crack the pad but if you put a lag bolt right next to an existing hole that hole might break out into the adjacent hole.

Comment: code is 36" from the fence.